# Syncfusion's SfSchedule doesn't handle different item types

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, syncfusion, sfschedule

**Situation**: I got the Syncfusion `SfSchedule` control in my UI. I bind my list of appointments to the `ItemsSource` like this:

```
<schedule:SfSchedule x:Name="MyCalendar"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Appointments}"
                     ... />
```

My `Appointments` property is a list of objects which implement an interface I wrote:

```
private ObservableCollection<ICalendarItem> _appointments;
public ObservableCollection<ICalendarItem> Appointments
{
    get => _appointments;
    private set => Set(ref _appointments, value);
}
```

I have two implementations for `ICalendarItem`: `SingleCalendarItem` and `RepetitiveCalendarItem`.

**Problem**: Syncfusion's schedule control works perfectly and displays my appointments for as long as my `Appointments` list contains of one of the calendar item types only, for instance only `SingleCalendarItem` or only `RepetitiveCalendarItem`.

The second I add both object types into my list, the schedule control displays nothing. It continues to display nothing even if I bound another list that consists of objects of type `SingleCalendarItem` only.

**Question**: It looks like the Syncfusion `SfSchedule` control gets a hiccup once the bound item source is a list consisting of multiple types even though they implement the same interface. Is someone able to confirm this is a bug in the `SfSchedule` and/or knows a workaround how I can bind different objects?

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly certain this is a **bug** in Syncfusion's `SfSchedule` control (as of August 2017). Found a workaround: I built a facade which holds any of the `ICalendarItem` objects and exposes their interface properties and methods:

```
public class CalendarItemFacade : ICalendarItem
{
    private ICalendarItem _calendarItem;
    public CalendarItemFacade(ICalendarItem calendarItem)
    {
        _calendarItem = calendarItem;
    }

    public DateTime StartTime => _calendarItem.StartTime;
    // All other interface implementations follow here
}
```

Instead of assigning a list of of different calendar item types to the `SfSchedule` property, I ensure that they are all of my facade type `CalendarItemFacade`.

**Update**: I reported this bug to Syncfusion: https://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac/incidents/185839. Syncfusion confirmed the issue. The bug is fixed since 14/9/2017 apparently - to be tested.